# How to determine the target content offset of a UIScrollView when dragging is finished?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UITableView and I want to determine what cells will be visible when the view stops moving, so that I can start loading the thumbnail images in advance.

I found the UIScrollViewDelegate function `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate`, but I still need a way to figure out where the UIScrollView is headed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset: as it gives you an estimated content offset of where the scrolling will stop.

Jonathan